# A 1 pixel gap only coming on iPad but fine on Safari and Chrome

Tags: iphone, html, css, ipad

[Here at this line after clouds](http://jitendra.skarp.dk/examples/testing/) which **will be only visible in iPad or iPhone**. Any idea how to solve it?

It's fine in all other desktop browsers.

[image]

CSS

```
#banner-inner { height: 270px;     margin: 0 auto;    position: relative;    width: 954px;}

.cloud-bottom { position: absolute; background: url(images/clouds_dark.png) repeat-x 0 bottom ; z-index: 1; width:100%;height:111px;bottom:0}

.cloud-top { position: absolute; background: url(images/clouds_light.png) repeat-x 0 bottom ; z-index: 4;width:100%;height:111px;bottom:0}
```

Comment: Perhaps try to define things in terms of `em` instead of `px`?

Comment: weird i dont even see that line. all i see are 2 dotted lines http://grab.by/adxo

Comment: @ corroded- Line will only be seen on ipad.

Comment: @Jitendra Vyas there is something funny going on with the graphic clouds_light.jpg. I've turned it opaque and there's a one pixel edge starting in the middle. I'll post it as non answer.

Comment: Does the line remain 1px if you zoom in, or is it bigger if you zoom in? If experienced on some sites of mine, that the line remains 1 physical 1px on the iphone, even if zoomed in. I just didnt bother fixing it.

Comment: Your animation makes me dizzy - I think it's because the clouds are going different ways.  I don't know what you are trying to accomplish but if it's [parallax scrolling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallax_scrolling) then you want them to go the same way, just have the back one move slower.

Comment: @gerben - if i zoom then this 1 px gap will be gone.

Comment: Seems like this issue also occurs in Safari 5.1.3 on OSX 10.3.7 also using WebKit. May also happen on Safari for Windows.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This seems to be a bug of the WebKit rendering engine on the iPad, when the page scale factor is less than 1.0. If you keep the page scale factor above 1.0, then the pixel gap does not show up. This can be done with a meta tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
```

I also found a simple page that demonstrate a similar issue (a rendering glitch on iPad only):

- [Rounding error with widths](http://www.hackvalue.nl/bug.html)

In the past, there have been a number of bugs reported for rounding issues in the WebKit engine:

- [WebKit Bug #5531](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=5531)
- [WebKit Bug #14956](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=14956)
- [WebKit Bug #18013](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=18013)

Comment: Thanks! Fixed my issue as well with a line showing up on Ipad!

Answer (score 1):

If disabling zoom is not wanted, and if the margin trick does not work (it probably works with background colors, but I could not get it to work with background images), here is another solution:

Make all background images 1 or 2 px bigger (cut them so they contain a 1 px duplicate of the graphics above/below), and use css background-size and background-position to ensure that the extra (unwanted) pixel is not shown - it will then only be used if the browser needs that extra pixel to cover the rendering gap.

Tested to fix the rendering bug on Android's 2.3's default browser (will test on iPhone & iPad on monday), plus zooming errors in Chrome on PC.

Answer (score 1):

I also solved the iOS sub pixel gap issue (on a full screen site) by using overflow-x: hidden; to stop side ways scrolling & viewpoint scale to stop pitch zooming. I also had holder divs set at width: 101%; and all the elements/image divs inside set to float: left;. This means the sub pixel gaps are all on the left hand site but pushed out of view by the holder div set at 101% width.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
#wrapper {
     margin: -2px auto;
... rest of your css....

}
```

may be there is a small resolution problem also so try this also

```
#wrapper {
    background-color: #fff;
... rest of your css....

}
```

one of them has to work :)

UPDATE:

I think i got it,

```
remove #wrapper background-color;

remove #banner-switcher background:
```

Comment: have you tested in multiple i pads?

Comment: I tested on iphone which gives same rendering. did you test on ipad I've added ur suggestion here you can test http://tinyurl.com/3l8xvh6

Comment: @lbu - No still same I've updated my example code . you can check in iphone or ipad line is still coming

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the the height of the `#banner` in `PX` not in `EM` And the hieght of cloud is 112px en 113px not 111px for both.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that this tends to occur when background images are up-scaled to match the resolution of the device. I suspect that this occurs due to a small amount of colour bleeding along the outer edges of your image which can usually be resolved by providing an additional version of your background for higher pixel density displays (i.e. retina in this case).

The following trick works great for me:

```
.your-thing {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image: url('img/your-background.png');
    background-size: 400px; /* width of "your-background.png" */
}

@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
only screen and (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
    .your-thing {
        /* override with version which is exactly 2x larger */
        background-image: url('img/your-background@2x.png');
    }
}
```

The above solution worked perfectly in my case.

Answer (score -1):

Funny beahviour, when transparancy is turned off. Even as jpg it does show this artifact. Looks like a bug in the webkit rendering engine.

[image]